# Why am I unable to send mail?

Tags: email, smtp, dovecot

I installed iredmail, and used it to set up a mail server on Debian 7 based VPS. Everything went fine, I can send and receive email via webmail. However on trying to send mail via SMTP on a client program (The Bat Professional, Windows 7), I am getting an error that "Sender address rejected: not logged in".

I am trying to find the cause of this issue. Here's the result of a manual telnet and attempting to send the mail. I've done this test via telnet on Windows on the same machine that the email client program resides on, and also checked via telnet on a remote debian server. Both times, email was successfully sent via telnet.

```
#telnet apollo.who.org 25
Trying 17.24.33.171...
Connected to apollo.who.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 apollo.who.org ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
HELO apollo.who.org
250 apollo.who.org
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
am9lbEBkcmpvZWwuaW5mbw==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
UTI3cG0zNU4yYg==
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
MAIL FROM:<joel@who.org>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<timothy@somewhere.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject:Test

Check success.
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5E150C2FF2
```

Manually sending email via smtp on telnet worked. The email was delivered. So it seems to be a problem configuring the client program?

Log of the client program shows:

```
 12/06/2013, 13:22:42: IMAP  - Connecting to IMAP server apollo.who.org on port 993
 12/06/2013, 13:22:44: IMAP  - Initiating TLS handshake
>12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - Certificate S/N: B25F55E1155DD8A8, algorithm: RSA (2048 bits), issued from 6/11/2013 5:26:55 PM to 6/9/2023 5:26:55 PM, for 1 host(s): apollo.who.org.
>12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - Owner: CN, GuangDong, ShenZhen, apollo.who.org, IT, apollo.who.org, root@apollo.who.org.
>12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - This certificate is self-issued.
 12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - TLS handshake complete
 12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - Connected to IMAP server (apollo.who.org)
>12/06/2013, 13:22:45: IMAP  - Dovecot ready.
 12/06/2013, 13:22:46: IMAP  - Authenticating (user: "joel@who.org", method: "LOGIN")...
 12/06/2013, 13:22:47: IMAP  - IMAP server authentication OK, server says "Logged in"
 12/06/2013, 13:23:21: SEND  - sending mail message(s) - 1 message(s) in queue
 12/06/2013, 13:23:21: SEND  - Connecting to SMTP server apollo.who.org on port 25
 12/06/2013, 13:23:21: SEND  - connected to SMTP server
 12/06/2013, 13:23:23: SEND  - WARNING: there were no compatible authentication mechanisms detected
 12/06/2013, 13:23:23: SEND  - sending message to joel@whos.org
 12/06/2013, 13:23:23: SEND  - The last address submitted was <joel@whos.org>
!12/06/2013, 13:23:23: SEND  - Message has not been sent. Server reply - 5.7.1 <joel@who.org>: Sender address rejected: not logged in
 12/06/2013, 13:23:24: SEND  - connection finished - 0 message(s) sent
 12/06/2013, 13:23:24: SEND  - Some messages were not sent - check the log for details
```

What settings should I use for configuring the client program to send email through this server?

Currently, I've tried:

1. Regular. The log as above
2. StartTTLS.
3. TLS

SMTP Authentication was set to on. Secure authentication was enabled.

Ports 25, 993 and 995 were checked.

Netstat results:

```
 #netstat -lpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1674/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1439/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3509/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2359/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3509/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9998          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1439/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10031         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2574/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1459/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1585/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3509/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1459/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1585/sshd
```

Comment: Was the `telnet` test done from the machine on which the client runs?

Comment: Of course not. :) It was from another VPS on a different DC.

Comment: That's not a very useful test, then, is it?  Could we get one that at least tries to simulate what the client's doing?  Also, details on how the client's set up for outgoing mail, particularly with respect to mandatory authentication requirements.

Comment: Looks like you've misconfigured your POP before SMTP log location..

Comment: @MadHatter I may have been misunderstood. I meant to say that telnet was run on another remote server, into the smtp server in question, to emulate the scenario.

Comment: @NickW The program automatically does a POP before SMTP. The log was displayed together.

Comment: Now I look at it again, you need to post what authentication methods you've configured on the server..

Comment: STARTTLS and SSL/TLS have been configured.

Comment: Droidzone, you were clear, I understood your test; it's just a bad test (it's like saying "My bathroom tap drips. I have checked the washer in the kitchen tap, and it's fine.  What could be wrong?").  **Please test again from the platform on which the SMTP client runs**.  And we still need to know what authentication methods have been configured on the **client**.

Comment: Ah. Well, I assumed that the tank which supplies water to both was faulty. :) I tried Regular, STARTTLS and TLS on the Client, and tried ports 25, 993, 995.

Comment: @MadHatter: I repeated the test with telnet on the same machine of the client. It again worked. The only difference was it asked for a different format for the email.

Comment: You keep telling me about **transport and encryption** settings on the client.  **I keep asking about authentication**.  Have you told the client, for example, that it has to authenticate to the server before it can send email?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, I have tried with and without SMTP authentication. The log was generated with SMTP authentication on (RFC 2554), requesting secure authentication.

Comment: Well, since the log is complaining about not being able to find any agreeable authentication methods, could you try again without requiring it, and post that log?

Comment: Ah. Without "secure authentication", it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the line

```
 12/06/2013, 13:23:23: SEND  - WARNING: there were no compatible authentication mechanisms detected
```

which, as we have found out, means that the server supports none of the authentication methods that the client has been configured to require to use.  When you reconfigure the client not to require any authentication methods that the server won't support, it works.

I wrote this up as an answer partly so you can accept it, thus putting the question to bed, but partly to warn you that that server appears to be running an open SMTP relay: we've confirmed that at least two separate hosts can use it to relay mail without authentication of any kind.

If it's behind a firewall, or it really only allows this relaying from a list of addresses that you control (and on which both the external test points happen to be), then all is good.  Otherwise, you're going to want to nail that relay down very quickly indeed, or you'll be carrying a shedload of spam onto the internet, and your reputation as a sending server will be in the toilet as far as the RBLs are concerned.